# Inverse exponential markov inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable, $t\geq 0.$ With the exponential Markov inequality, we know that
$$
P(X\geq t)\leq e^{-\theta t}\mathbb E \left[ e^{\theta X} \right] \textrm{ for all } \theta \geq 0.
$$
**Problem:** However, I'd like to prove estimate of the other direction, that is
$$
P(X\leq t) \leq e^{\theta t} \mathbb E \left[ e^{-\theta X} \right].
$$
I tried using the formula from above and the counter-probability but could not prove the statement. Is there maybe another, better way?

Comment: You just do the derivation over again: split the integration for $E[e^{-\theta X}]$ at $t$ and use that $e^{-\theta x}$ reaches its minimum value on $(-\infty,t]$ at $x=t$.

Comment: Another way to look at it is to apply the original formula to $-X$: $P(-X \geq t) \leq e^{-\theta t} E[e^{\theta (-X)}]$. Then replace $t$ by $-t$ to change the notation to match the desired formula.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your thoughts, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\theta>0$
$$
P(X\leq t)  =P(\theta X\leq \theta t)=P(e^{\theta X}\leq e^{\theta t}) =P(e^{-\theta X}\geq e^{-\theta t}) \leq e^{\theta t} E[e^{-\theta X}].
$$
The last line is Markov inequality.